# Grails applications and version control

Tags: svn, version-control, grails, groovy

Which directories/files should be excluded when placing a Grails application under version control?  I don't want non-source files or artifacts to be carried in SVN for my project.

Comment: I got so pissed of at Subversion when using Grails that I switched to Mercurial. Making SVN ignore all those runtime created Grails files was a nightmare!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

here's my .gitignore (it probably contains alot of junk)

```
.idea/
stacktrace.log
test/reports/
etc/errors.txt
bin-groovy/
.classpath
.project
*.war
web-app/plugins/
web-app/resources/
classes/
test/reports/
```

Note that this is for grails 1.1.1. (I think before grails 1.1, plugins were stored in `/plugins` instead of `web-app/plugins`.

Answer (score 5):

Grails.org has [specific instructions](http://www.grails.org/Checking+Projects+into+SVN) on checking your project into SVN.

Comment: Those are outdated for Grails 1.1.x

Answer (score 0):

You should exclude the "test/reports" directory in your root folder. It's also useful to exclude "stacktrace.log".

If you are using JS-Libraries you could think of excluding them too and write a little script for always getting the latest bugfix version. Modern JS-Libraries can be very large and it's not very useful to clutter your VCS with old versions of your frameworks. An exception is a jump to a new major version of a library or a tag. In this case you should definitely keep an old version.

Comment: Disagree with "You should exclude the "test" directory", you'd definitely want unit and integration tests under source control.

Comment: You are right I meant the "test/reports" directory. Already changed it. Thank you.