# grails and version control specific to plugins

Tags: version-control, grails

I am using 1.3.7 on a windows system, the plugins are placed in a different folder and I have made a few changes in the code related to the plugins.

I now need to check in this project into svn, how do i go about doing it ? specifically how do i check in he plugins ?

When a team mate of mine checks out this project, where will he find the plugins ?

I realize that similar questions have been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/956445/grails-applications-and-version-control) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201578/what-grails-project-files-should-not-be-added-to-version-control-grails-1-3-x)

However they do not address this specific problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plugins you have made need to be made inline. i.e. they will be in your grails-app folder.

To make a plugin inline create a folder say "custom-plugins" in your grails-app folder and copy the modified plugin there. Now in your BuildConfig.groovy add following lines

grails.plugin.location.'plugin-name'="custom-plugins/plugin-name"

repeat this for different plugins you have changed.

I personally prefer to add "custom" in the name of modified plugin to differentiate it from original.

Comment: Any disadvantages related to making a plugin inline ?, If no how come grails does not adopt this behaviour by default ?, if no changes are made to the plugins and I only check in the core project without the plugins , is it expected that the other team members checkout the project and then install the plugins ?

Comment: I have not come across any disadvantage of this approach. if no changes are made to plugins, it is expected that they are downloaded from repos directly and they will be automatically installed during run-app, other members do not need to do much.

Comment: grails.plugin.location.'plugin-name'="custom-plugins/plugin-name" shoudl be grails.plugin.location.'plugin-name'="grails-app/custom-plugins/plugin-name"